# Como obtener y que me arroje de resultado el nombre de la clase de mi proyecto

Tags: java

Buenas quiero ver como obtener y que me de resutado el nombre de mi clase de mi proyecto por fis es lo unico que me falta para completar mi programa gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenida. Es recomendable echar un ojo al [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) con el fin de formular una pregunta correctamente. Es necesario que añadas el código relevante a la pregunta para poder ayudarte de la mejor forma posible.

Comment: a mira lo que quiero es que el programa lo estoy haciendo en consola y quiero que me de el nombre de la clase osea el nombre de la clase ese va ser mi resultado pero tengo un problema que me da el nombre del paquete y de mi clase pero yo solo quiero que me de el nombre de la clase y asi tengo mi condigo

Comment: String sClassName  = new String (Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName().toString());              System.out.println("Esta clase se llama: "+sClassName2+"\n");

Comment: Edita tu pregunta haciendo clic en **editar** y añade ese código. Los comentarios no son para estructurar código ya que no se entiende nada.

Answer (score 1):

es muy sencillo, puedes utilizar este método para solucionar tu problema

```
public String nombre() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```